# Why do I see many "kernel: vif ...: Guest Rx stalled" / "Guest Rx ready" messages?

Tags: virtualization, bridge, linux-kernel, sles

Since upgrading a Xen host that also is a node in a pacemaker cluster from SLES15 SP2 to SLES15 SP3, I see these messages roughly every 30 seconds, and I wonder:

- What are these messages telling me? No traffic?
- What causes these messages? A change in the kernel? I'm running 5.3.18-150300.59.43-default.
- What can I do to make them go away?

The messages look like this:

```text
kernel: vif vif-6-2 vif6.2: Guest Rx stalled
kernel: vif vif-6-2 vif6.2: Guest Rx ready
```

As it seems these message repeat about every 30 seconds, and they seem to be related to VMs (PVM) that have the corresponding interface in "link down" state.